# What happens if two breeds of dogs have puppies?

Tags: the-sims

What happens if you mixed let's say a golden retriever with a greyhound? Will they mix or come out as a golden retriever OR a greyhound?

Comment: Not sure at all but, making a mixing system would be hard to code/design. I say random. But I'm not sure. (never played sims freeplay)

Comment: Can you even breed dogs in Freeplay? I played daily for more than a year and haven't seen any option to have puppies, let alone breed them. I don't even remember there being an option to chose the dog's sex. Plus, there's no genetics for human Sims, either, that I have seen. As far as I know, genetics and breeding are exclusive to the full version of the game (PC or console.)

Comment: @ardaozkal, from Game Dev POV, this feature would be hard to code - however - the sims typically exhibit the same feature to differant degrees. I would say it would be entirely possible, due to deriving mostly from an already-in-place system